# AWS EC2 jmap heap dump

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jmap

I have an AWS EC2 instance running Tomcat facing some OutOfMemory issues. I have:

- run `sudo yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel`
- run `sudo -u tomcat jmap -F -dump:format=b,file=/foo/heapdumps/heapdump.bin <pid>`

The `jmap` fails with

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.runTool(JMap.java:201)
at sun.tools.jmap.JMap.main(JMap.java:130)
Caused by: java.lang.InternalError: Metadata does not appear to be polymorphic
at sun.jvm.hotspot.types.basic.BasicTypeDataBase.findDynamicTypeForAddress(BasicTypeDataBase.java:278)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.runtime.VirtualBaseConstructor.instantiateWrapperFor(VirtualBaseConstructor.java:102)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.oops.Metadata.instantiateWrapperFor(Metadata.java:68)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.DictionaryEntry.klass(DictionaryEntry.java:71)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.Dictionary.classesDo(Dictionary.java:66)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary.classesDo(SystemDictionary.java:190)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.memory.SystemDictionary.allClassesDo(SystemDictionary.java:183)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.writeClasses(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:954)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.utilities.HeapHprofBinWriter.write(HeapHprofBinWriter.java:427)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.run(HeapDumper.java:62)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.startInternal(Tool.java:260)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:223)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.HeapDumper.main(HeapDumper.java:83)
... 6 more
```

Does anyone have a suggestion what could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Solution found.

I had to run `sudo yum --enablerepo='*-debug*' install java-1.8.0-openjdk-debuginfo` as well.